# uitableviewcell imageview resizes (horizontally only) when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, imageview, sdwebimage

hi i have a uitableviewcell, using the default uitableview cell provided in ios
in the cell.imageView, its image is populated via an url of an image
like so

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:movie.show_image_url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

it loads everything fine initially, but in the simulator when i select a row, i can see the elements in the cell (except the cheveron) shifts to the left, and this makes the imageview appears shorter in width

i am not sure why, if i replace the imageview with a static image stored in the app, say placeholder.png, then i don't observe this issue.

can someone help?

Answer (score 8):

I was having this problem too, and found a really simple solution to it—overriding -layoutSubViews in your UITableViewCell class (and subclassing UITableViewCell if that hasn't been done).

For the details, see [SDWebImage fixed width cell images](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2011/11/sdwebimage-fixed-width-cell-images/) (found while perusing the [SDWebImage github repo](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)).

The technique proposed in the article involves controlling the UIImageView, and two UILabel, geometries in a standard UITableViewCell available in IB. I'm using a custom cell, and was able to fix the problem by simply overriding how the UIImageView is laid out:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.thumbnailView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          THUMBNAIL_WIDTH,
                                          THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT
                                          );

}
```

(note that THUMBNAIL_WIDTH and THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT are just macros, both set to 71).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had a strange bug where my custom cells would get stretched out when scrolling and getting cellForRowAtIndexPath: called. I triple checked all the basic stuff then found this gem of an answer! I had to reset the frames of the views that were direct children of my CustomTableViewCells.contentView to fix it!